# Why adding new entity just to modify another one

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm reading the source of an ASP.NET Core example project (MSDN) and try to understand all.

There's an **Edit** razor page which shows the values of an entity record in `<input>` fields allowing the user to see and change different fields of a given record. There's this line:

```
Movie = await _context.Movie.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
...
_context.Attach(Movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I don't understand why it adds a new entity and change its `EntityState` to `Modified`, instead of fetch the record and change it then call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. No entity is being added here. In fact, it's doing exactly what you're saying it should (pulling the entity from the database, modifying it, and then save the changes). Perhaps if you post more code or provide a link to what you're looking at, it might be more clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that their example is loading the movie in one call, passing it to the view, then in another update action, passing the modified entity from the view to the controller, which is attaching it, setting it's state to modified, and then calling save changes.

IMHO this is an extremely bad practice with EF for a number of reasons, and I have no idea why Microsoft uses it in examples (other than that it makes CRUD look easy-peazy).

1. By serializing entities to the view, you are serializing typically far more data to send across the wire than your view actually needs. You give malicious, or curious users far more information about your system than you should.
2. You are bound to run into serializer errors with bi-directional references. ("A" has reference to "B" which has a reference back to "A") Serializers (like JSON) generally don't like these.
3. You are bound to run into performance issues with lazy loading calls as the serializer "touches" references. When dealing with collections of results, the resulting lazy load calls can blow performance completely out of the water.
4. Without lazy loading enabled, you can easily run into issues where referenced data is passed as #null or potentially incomplete collections due to the Context possibly having some referenced data in the cache that it can pull and associate to the entity, but not the complete set of child records.
5. By passing entities back to the controller you expose your system to unintentional modifications by which an attacker can modify the entity data in ways that you do not intend it to be modified, then when you attach it, set the state to modified, and save, you overwrite the data state. I.e. change FKs, or otherwise alter data that is not supported, or even displayed by your UI.
6. You are bound to run into stale data issues where data can have changed between the point you read the entity initially and the point it is saved. Attaching and saving takes a brutal "last-in-wins" approach to concurrent data.

My general advice is to:
1. Leverage `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` to populate ViewModel classes with just the fields your view will need. This avoids the risks of lazy loads, and minimizes the data passed to the client. (Faster, and reveals nothing extra about your system)
2. Trust absolutely nothing coming back from the client. Validate the returned view model object, then only after you're satisfied it is legit, load the entity(ies) from the context and copy the applicable fields across. This also gives you the opportunity to evaluate row versioning to handle concurrency issues.

Disclaimer: You certainly can address most of my pointed out issues while still passing entities back & forth, but you definitely leave the door wide open to vulnerabilities and bugs creeping in when someone just defaults to an attach & save, or lazy loads start creeping in.